# Delphi 10.1 При запускании появляется ошибка Access violation at address 00409BA2 in module "Project1.exe''. Read of address 00000008

Tags: delphi-10-berlin

[image: Вот так выглядит интерфейс программы, ошибка выдается после нажатия кнопки "Расчет"]    unit Unit1;

```
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Math, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    Lable1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Label7: TLabel;
    Label8: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    Edit6: TEdit;
    Edit7: TEdit;
    Edit8: TEdit;
    Edit9: TEdit;
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;
procedure RAV (var U1, U2, gamma: Real);
var U: Real;
begin
    U := U1 + U2;
    U1:= U2;
    if U > 4 then U := U - 4;
    U2:= U;
    gamma := U/4;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var    // описываем переменные
t_rab, ljamda, zagrVS, zagrAV, n, k, tr : Integer;
dt, vygr: Real;
t_rab_str, zagrVS_str, zagrAV_str, n_str, k_str, tr_str,
ljamda_str, vygr_str, dt_str: String;
code: Integer;
Fil: TextFile;
begin   // переводим переменные из строкового типа в числовой
t_rab_str:= Edit1.Text;
Val(t_rab_str,t_rab,code);
zagrVS_str:= Edit2.Text;
Val(zagrVS_str,zagrVS,code);
zagrAV_str:= Edit3.Text;
Val(zagrAV_str,zagrAV,code);
n_str:= Edit4.Text;
Val(n_str,n,code);
k_str:= Edit5.Text;
Val(k_str,k,code);
tr_str:= Edit6.Text;
Val(tr_str,tr,code);
ljamda_str:= Edit7.Text;
Val(ljamda_str,ljamda,code);
vygr_str:= Edit8.Text;
Val(vygr_str,vygr,code);
dt_str:= Edit9.Text;
Val(dt_str,dt,code);
AssignFile(fil, 'vvod.txt');
rewrite(fil);
   //Записываем переменные в текстовый файл "Ввод"
  begin
Writeln(fil,'Время работы аэропорта, час:');
writeln(fil,t_rab);
Writeln(fil,'Загрузка ВС, пасс:');
writeln(fil,zagrVS:5);
writeln(fil,'Загрузка автобуса, пасс:');
writeln(fil,zagrAV:5);
writeln(fil,'Количество перронов:');
writeln(fil,n:3);
writeln(fil,'Количество автобусов:');
writeln(fil,k:3);
writeln(fil,'Время выполнения рейса автобусом, мин:');
writeln(fil,tr:3);
writeln(fil,'Интенсивность прилетающих ВС, ВС/час:');
writeln(fil,ljamda);
writeln(fil,'Время выгрузки пасс на перрон, мин:');
writeln(fil,vygr:3:2);
writeln(fil,'Шаг дискретизации, мин:');
writeln(fil,dt:3:2);
  end;
CloseFile(fil);
ShowMessage('Значения сохранены');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
per: array of Integer;     //  массив перронов
avt: array of Integer;      // массив автобусов
avtper: array of Integer;     //  массив привязки автобуса к перрону
Tosv: array of Real;           //  момент освобождения автобуса
Tpribpass: array of Real;      //  момент прибытия пассажиров на перрон
Tozh: array of Real;           //  время ожидания пассажиров посадки на автобус
t_rab,   //  время смены
zagrVS,  // загрузка ВС
zagrAV,  // загрузка автобуса
n,       // количество перронов
k,       // количество автобусов
tr,      // время кругорейса
i, j,    // счетчик
dl_och,  // длина очереди
Suml,    // суммарная длина очереди
srl,     // средняя длина очереди
Lmax,     // max длина очереди
p, y, a: Integer;
dt,      // шаг дисретизации
vygr,    // время выгрузки пассажиров из ВС
tvh,     // момент прибытия ВС
t,       // текущее время
gamma,   // псевдослучайная величина
U1, U2,  // Числа, используемые при вычислении случайного числа
maxTozh, // мах время ожидания автобуса
srTozh,  // среднее время ожидания
sumTozh, // суммарное время ожидания
deltaT,  //интервал между подачей автобусов
maxDeltaT, // max интервал между подачей автобусов
srDeltaT,  // средний интервал между подачей автобусов
sumDeltaT, // суммарный интервал между подачей автобусов
ljamda,  // интенсивность прибытия ВС
sch_obsl // счетчик обслуженных пассажиров
: Real;
t_rab_str, zagrVS_str, zagrAV_str, n_str, k_str, tr_str,
ljamda_str, vygr_str, dt_str: String;
code: Integer;
Fil: TextFile;
begin
AssignFile(Fil, 'vvod.txt');
    Reset(Fil);
    while not EOF(fil) do
  //Считываем данные с текстового файла "Ввод"
    begin
        readln(fil);
        readln(fil, t_rab_str);
        readln(fil);
        readln(fil, zagrVS_str);
        readln(fil);
        readln(fil, zagrAV_str);
        readln(fil);
        readln(fil, n_str);
        readln(fil);
        readln(fil, k_str);
        readln(fil);
        readln(fil, tr_str);
    readln(fil);
    readln(fil, ljamda_str);
    readln(fil);
    readln(fil, vygr_str);
    readln(fil);
    readln(fil, dt_str);
    end;
    CloseFile(fil);
      Val(t_rab_str, t_rab, code);
      Val(zagrVS_str, zagrVS, code);
      Val(zagrAV_str, zagrAV, code);
      Val(n_str, n, code);
      Val(k_str, k, code);
      Val(tr_str, tr, code);
      Val(ljamda_str, ljamda, code);
      Val(vygr_str, vygr, code);
      Val(dt_str, dt, code);
    //  Вычисляем первичные данные, задаем длины массивам
    t_rab := t_rab * 60;    //  Переводим часы в минуты
  ljamda:=ljamda/60;
    gamma := 0;
    SetLength(per, n);
  SetLength(avt, k);
    SetLength(avtper, k);
  SetLength(Tosv, k);
  SetLength(Tpribpass, 28800); // Задаем размер массиву прибытия пассажиров на перрон
  SetLength(Tozh, zagrVS);
    U1 := 3.14159265;  U2 := 0.542101887;   //  Исходные псевдослучайные величины
    t := 0;             //счетчик текущего времени
    Suml := 0;      //суммарная длина очереди
  srl := 0;       //средняя длина очереди
    Lmax := 0;        //максимальная длина очереди
    Tozh := 0;      //время ожидания автобуса пассажиром (на перроне)
    maxTozh := 0;   //мах время ожидания автобуса
    srTozh := 0;      //среднее время ожидания
    sumTozh := 0;   //суммарное время ожидания автобуса
    deltaT := 0;    //интервал между подачей автобусов
    maxDeltaT := 0; //макс интервал между подачей автобусов
    srDeltaT := 0;  //средннее значение между подачей автобусов
    sumDeltaT := 0; // суммарный интервал
for j:=1 to k do
    begin
        avtper[j] := 0;     // привязка автобуса к перрону, пока никакой не привязан
        avt[j] := 0;        // все автобусы свободны на стоянке аэропорта
    end;
RAV(U1, U2, gamma);         // Генерируем случайную величину gamma для прибытия самолета
tvh := ln(gamma)/(-ljamda); // Генерируем первое прибытие самолета
//  ЗАПУСК РАБОТЫ
While t < t_rab Do     // пока смена идет
  Begin
  t := t + dt;  //  Ход времени
        //  Обслуживание в аэропорту
  for i := 1 to n do
 begin
  if t >= tvh  then //  Самолет прилетел
  begin
  per[i]:=1;               // перрон занят прибывшим самолетом
  dl_och:=zagrVS;
  for a:= 1 to zagrVS do
    begin
    Tpribpass[a]:=t+vygr;  // время прибытия пассажиров на перрон
    end;
      while dl_och>0 do        // до тех пор, пока на перроне остаются пассажиры
        begin
         for j := 1 to k do   // работаем с автобусами
         if avt[j]=0 then     // если автобус свободен
            begin
            avtper[j]:=i;      // номер перрона, привязанного к автобусу
            avt[j]:=1;         // автобус занят

            if j = k then          //если это последний автобус
            deltaT := Abs(Tosv[j] - Tosv[1]) // то интервал между прибытием автобусов находим между последним и первым автобусом (закольцовываем список)
            else deltaT := Abs(Tosv[j] - Tosv[j+1]); //иначе находим между предыдущим и последующим автобусом

            if deltaT > maxDeltaT then maxDeltaT := deltaT;  // находим max интервал
            sumDeltaT := sumDeltaT + deltaT;                 // суммарный интервал

            Tosv[j]:=tvh+tr;   // автобус освободится к этому времени
            if t>Tosv[j] then         //если время освобождения автобуса наступило
            avt[j]:=0;                //освободи автобус
            dl_och:=dl_och-zagrAV; //длина очереди уменьшается на кол-во увезенных пассажиров

            if dl_och > Lmax then
            Lmax:=dl_och; //переписываем максимальную длину очереди

            for a := 1 to zagrVS do
              begin
              Tozh[a]:=Abs(t-Tpribpass[a]);  //время ожидания
              sumTozh:=sumTozh+Tozh[a]; //сумма времени ожидания
              if Tozh[a]>maxTozh then
              maxTozh:=Tozh[a];         //находим max время ожидания пассажира
            end;
           end;
        end;

  end;
  end;
     tvh:=tvh-ln(gamma)/(-ljamda);   //прибытие следующего самолета
end;
//ОКОНЧАНИЕ РАБОТЫ
    srTozh := sumTozh/zagrVS;
    srDeltaT := sumDeltaT/k;
  sch_obsl := ljamda*t_rab*zagrVS;
             // ЗАПИСЫВАЕМ РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ В ФАЙЛ
    AssignFile(fil, 'result.txt');
    Rewrite(fil);
    try
        Writeln(fil, 'Интенсивность потока ВС = ', ljamda:4:1, '  ВС/мин');
        Writeln(fil);
        Writeln(fil, 'Число обслуженных пассажиров = ', sch_obsl, ' пасс-в');
        Writeln(fil);
        Writeln(fil, 'Максимальное время ожидания автобуса пассажиром = ', maxTozh:4:2, ' минут; Среднее время ожидания пассажиров автобуса = ', srTozh:4:2);
        writeln(fil);
        Writeln(fil, 'Максимальная длина очереди = ', Lmax, ' пасс-в');
        Writeln(fil);
        Writeln(fil, 'Максимальный интервал движения автобусов = ', maxDeltaT:4:2, ' минут; Среднее значение интервала движения автобусов = ', srDeltaT:4:2);
    finally
        CloseFile(fil);
    end;
if True then
    begin
    ShowMessage('Расчёт выполнен');
        Exit;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
fil:TextFile;
r:string;
begin
Form2.Memo1.Lines.Clear;
AssignFile(fil,'result.txt');
Reset(fil);
while not EOF(fil) do
begin
Readln(fil,r);
Form2.Memo1.Lines.Text:=Form2.Memo1.Lines.Text+r+Chr(13);
end;
CloseFile(fil);
Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Close;
end;

end.
```

вот код
в отладчике выдает сообщение (прикреплю скрин)
[image: ругается на строчку Tozh[a]:=Abs(t-Tpribpass[a]); //время ожидания]

Comment: **uses Unit2;** **Project1.dpr**  Не приложены эти 2 файла... а приложеный код - не может вызывать указаную ошибку при запуске приложения, он может ее вызвать только по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду под "не приложены"?

Comment: Под "не приложены" - то что вы данные файлы не приложили в виде кода(как поступили с **Unit1.pas**), тот файл который вы выложили(**Unit1.pas**) к такой ошибке при запуске приводить не может, либо вы умышленно не говорите что это происходит по нажатию одной из кнопок(**Какой именно? и на кой черт нам остальная куча картинок?**, почитайте как задавать вопросы, там написано что нужно привести **минимально необходимый** пример кода для воспроизведения ошибки)